# EMF - Intensive or Extensive Property

Tags: electrochemistry, reduction-potential

In electrochemistry, I know that standard emf of a cell (also called standard electrode potential (E°)) is an intensive property.

But, I wanted to know whether non-standard emf will also be intensive or extensive?

(Also, in general, is electromotive force intensive or extensive?) (I mean emf used in other topics like electromagnetism)

Comment: @Poutnik Most websites say that it will be intensive but when we change concentration of electrolyte then cell's potential also changes, why is that?

Comment: You pay twice as much, you get twice as much - that's what "extensive" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being [intensive or extensive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) is not related to changing of system properties like concentrations. It is related to scalability of systems.

If you change the system scale, like doubling or halving it, and if the property remains the same, like temperature, density, composition, equilibrium EMF, it is the **intensive** property.

If you change the system scale and the property changes proportionally to the scaling, it is the **extensive** property, like mass, volume, energy.

If you change the system scale and the property changes, but not proportionally  to the scaling, it is neither **extensive** neither **intensive** property.  Like the object surface, galvanic resistance or the non-standard non-equilibrium EMF, where level of the [electrode polarization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_(electrochemistry)) can be scale dependent.